# Java: Are streams and sockets private to threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a threaded server. I use a threadpool to create a bunch of threads that process data from each client. Each thread needs to send and receive information from a second server. I have created a class that handles the connection to the second server including generating the inputObjectStream/OutputObjectStram; each thread creates a new instance of the connections class so I thought that streams would be independent negating the need to synchronize the connection class however when I don't synchronize the streams don't create successfully.

From what I understand the sockets and streams should be private to each thread, am I wrong?

Here is a very brief pseudo-code structure of what I'm trying to do just to clarify.

```
public static void main(){
   //Create the threads
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
   for(int i=0; i<X;i++){
     Runnable worker = new ProcessCommands(list, GeneratorResponse);
     executor.execute(worker);
   }
   executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
}

public ProcessCommands(List<String> list, String threadName){

    public void run(){
    Connection Connect = new Connection();
    Connect.getData();
    }
}

public class Connection implements Serializable{
  private static Socket WG_Socket= null;
  private static String WG_addr = "b132.seng.uvic.ca";
  private static int WG_Port = 44433;
  public Connection(){
  }

  public int getData(){
   WG_Socket =  new Socket(WG_addr,WG_Port);

   ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(WG_Socket.getOutputStream());

   out.writeObject("Send Data");

   ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(WG_Socket.getInputStream());

   return (Integer)in.readObject();
}
}
```

Comment: You create a new instance, but WG_Socket is static. So all the instances share the same variable. This variable should be a local variable of getData(). The other ones should be constants, i.e. static final. Please, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: You life will be simpler if a Socket is only use by one Thread, but nothing enforces this.  You have a Socket being used by multiple threads at once.

Comment: They're only as private or as public as you make them. Nothing inherent. Static Sockets are rarely if ever correct.

Comment: Static anything is rarely, if ever, correct in multithreaded apps.  I cannot understand why devs. continually do these static declarations in such OO classes - it's like some sort of suicide wish.